# Does 「私は緊張してです私の日本語学習ついて」 read properly?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, learning, english-to-japanese

I'm trying to say, "I'm nervous about learning Japanese" or "I'm nervous about my Japanese learning." Does 「私は緊張してです私の日本語学習ついて」 communicate that? If not, how should I communicate it?

Comment: Basic Japanese sentence structure is subject-object-verb.

Comment: I think there are probably many ways to say this but here is one idea (not guaranteed to be the best way): "僕は日本語を勉強すると思うと怖いです". You could use "緊張します", but "怖い" (literally 'scared') sounds more natural to me.

Comment: Really? 怖い sounds quite a bit stronger than nervous...

Comment: “私は緊張してです私の日本語学習ついて” is not only grammatically but doesn’t make sense. I don’t know what you are going to say. 

Are you saying “I always feel nervous when I’m learning Japanese language,” “I’m excited to learn Japanese language.” or “I feel nervous to speak about learning Japanese (before audience)?  You need to make it clear what you are going to say in English so that we can suggest you a proper way of expressing it in Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

As other people mentioned in the comments, your grammar is off in that sentence. I would phrase it like this:

> 私は日本語を勉強することについて不安に思っています。

Side note: Even in English, I think the sentence "I'm nervous about learning Japanese" is a bit vague without more context. The reason I say this is because the action of learning a language by itself does not typically inspire feelings of nervousness, unlike, for example, learning how to skydive.

Maybe "I'm nervous about learning Japanese" is hinting at something like "My first Japanese class is coming up soon, so I'm nervous." or "I'm nervous about learning Japanese because we have to stand up and speak in class, and I've never been good at that sort of thing."?